# React router send URL with params

Tags: reactjs

Hello I just created one component where i get a product and i have description values ​​etc each product has a code and the page url is / products how could I put the url with

```
/ product / category/codproduct
```

and other parameters the product code would always vary

could i do this using redux?

```
    <Router>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/product/(category/codproduct)' component={description} />
      <Route path='/settings' component={Settings} />
    </Router >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send a prop with react router like product id , the in you product page do an api call get get product data

```
let {productId, category} = ths.state
    <Route
      path='/dashboard'
      component={() => <ProductPage productId={product} category={category/>}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your route define the parameters

```
      <Router>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/product/:category/:codproduct' component={description} />
          <Route path='/settings' component={Settings} />
        </div>
      </Router>
```

and then use it in the description component as follows

```
const description = (props) => {
const {category, codproduct} = props.match.params

return(...)
}

export default withRouter(description)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/product/:category/:codproduct' render={(props) => {
          <Description category={props.match.params.category} codproduct={props.match.params.codproduct} />
        }} />
        <Route path='/settings' component={Settings} />
      </Switch>
    </Router >
```

you will get the props in particular component

```
import {Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
```

if you are matching exact url

```
this.props.category and this.props.codproduct
```